# Download all data, filter locally OR Download filtered data only

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a store web app React front-end, Firebase on the back with Firestore as DB.

I have 500 items for the store. I'm expecting Desktop only clients.

**Is it better practice to:**

- Download all the items at once into local array of objects during initial loading and use `.filter()` for filtering; **OR**
- Call the database to return only filtered data whenever the client filters.

**For downloading all at once, I'm thinking:**

1. It is (*maybe*) faster for each filter since it is done locally. I'm not sure at what size an array of objects becomes slower to filter than getting a response from a server. Since clients will only be Desktop, I'm thinking quite large.
2. Doesn't require communication with server for every filter. Firestore also counts quotas in number of reads, write, or transactions, so it should reduce my quota use.
3. Repeating same filter on same client doesn't require request for same data again. As in a client might filter, then reset the filter, and do the same filter again.

**For downloading filtered results only, I'm thinking:**

1. Filtering on server and responding back (*maybe*) faster than `.filter()` locally.
2. Clients always get most up-to-date information.
3. Faster initial loading.

I know it may depend on the database structure since Firestore is shallow query, so I structured the data to be as shallow as possible with no sub-collections in documents.

I'm just comparing vanilla stuff so no Algolia or Elastic on the back and no searching or indexing libraries on the front.

Answer (score 3):

500 is a very small number of documents.  Modern desktop systems will have absolutely no problems sorting and filtering that list.  You might be more upset about the bill from Cloud Firestore for making it sort and filter all your queries all the time, than the performance of just downloading once and doing it all locally.  It depends on the behavior you expect of the users of your app though (and also the size of the documents, and the speeds of their connections).

You might observe some performance problems when you get to 50,000 items (on low-end desktops), but likely not enough to inconvenience anyone.  Try writing a few lines of code to sort or filter 50,000 random integers and see how long it takes.  Your actual application code should perform not much differently against real data.

You'll do even better if you're able to cache documents locally without having to query them all again.  Consider adding a document field for last update, and query for only documents updated since the last query.  You'll save even more money and time.

In the end you should benchmark your use cases to get some practical data to work with.  Spend less time speculating and more time measuring.

Comment: However at 50,000 items, I think the initial download will be more of a problem then filtering (in terms of time). I will try simulating the local filter for timing, but what would be a realistic simulation for the timing getting 50,000 items from Firestore?

Comment: Generate random data the approximates the anticipated size of each document.  Then benchmark.